# Updating bokeh standalone html

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using bokeh to trend some timeseries data, I periodically generate an 'results.html' file every few minutes, however when I do so I overwrite the previous file.
Currenlty I get some helpful warnings from Bokeh, telling me the file already exists and that it will be overriden, this is nice, but after a while a little annoying, as I am intentionally overwritting the file.

Is there any way to supress these warnings, or at least suppress the INFO messages that bokeh provides?

I am not using bokeh server its all meant to be standalone.

Also and a little seperately, what date time format does bokeh expect when using :

> x_axis_type= 'datetime'

Currently I'm using python time module

> epoch_time = time.time()

(time since epoch as an integer) which works fine. But I would very much like to pass in time stamps along the lines of:

> 2011-05-03 17:45:35.177000

But not sure exactly how the timestamp I provide should be formatted. Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of any such warnings in recent versions, and a cursory search did not turn up anything. Without example code to replicate what you are seeing, or the exact message you are seeing, it is impossible to help more.

Comment: INFO:bokeh.core.state:Session output file 'results_file.html' already exists, will be overwritten.

Comment: any ideas on how I should format date and time information for use with Bokeh's x_axis_type? is time.time() the only option?

Comment: OK that message is here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/core/state.py#L215-L216 If you want to submit a Pull Request to e.g., change that to a `debug` message instead of an `info` message, it would be accepted.

Comment: For the other, you need some kind of date time object (i.e. from the standard `datetime` module, or any of the datetime types from NumPy or Pandas), or the numeric value since epoch. String timestamps are not converted.

Comment: Thanks @bigreddot. Just so I'm clear if I have my timestamp as datetime.utcnow() OR datetime.now(). I should be fine, is that right? If I store the timestamp in a SQLite database table, I can set the column type to be DATETIME, is this correct?

Comment: I don't know enough about SQLite to say for sure, I think you will just have to try and see. If the python SQLite API returns a datetime object of some sort for a query to a DATETIME column, then my guess would be yes.